# What regex matches any text that is entirely between square brackets?

Tags: regex

So if I have these lines:

```
test 1
[test 2]
[test] 3
test [4]
[test][5]
[te]st[6]
```

I would like only the 2nd and 5th lines to be matched (`[test 2]`, `[test][5]`).

I know that we can match what's inside a pair of square brackets with regex
`\[.*?\]`

But how do we deal with multiple pairs and how to tell it to not match the line if there's anything outside of the square brackets?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(?:\[[^][]*])+$
^(?:\[[^\]\[]*\])+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/omMvTJ/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group (remove `?:` if you do not care or if non-capturing groups are not supported):

  - `\[` - a `[` char
  - `[^][]*` - zero or  more chars other than `]` and `[`
  - `]` - a `]` char
- `)+` - one or more repetitions of the pattern sequence inside the group
- `$` - end of string.

NOTE: in some regex flavors you need to escape more `[` / `]` than in others, so to play safe, I added the fully escaped regex version.

Comment: That seems to work perfectly, thank you sir!  
And thanks for the explanation and the demo, this helps in understanding why it works.

Comment: Well, even if this goes beyond the scope of my problem, it wouldn't match:
`[te[st]6]`
while there's nothing that isn't enclosed in at least one layer of brackets. 
But yeah, this wasn't in my examples.

Comment: @AndreiToroplean You may try `^(\[(?:[^][]++|\g<1>)*])+$` then. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/omMvTJ/2).